# Easier way to write If hash includes then - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, model

I have the following in an initialize method on my model:

```
@home_phone = contact_hash.fetch('HomePhone')
```

However, sometimes I need this instead:

```
@home_phone = contact_hash.fetch('number')
```

Also, sometimes neither of those will be true and I will need the `home_phone` attribute to be empty.

How can I write this out without creating a big loop like so:

```
if contact_hash.has_key?('HomePhone')
  @home_phone = contact_hash.fetch('HomePhone')
elsif contact_hash.has_key?('number')
  @home_phone = contact_hash.fetch('number')
else 
  @home_phone = ""
end
```

Comment: As an aside, you might want to also check that the value of what you are returning isn't an empty string.  Like `if contact_hash['HomePhone'] && contact_hash[HomePhone] =! ''`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try

```
@home_phone = contact_hash.fetch('HomePhone', contact_hash.fetch('number', ""))
```

or better

```
@home_phone = contact_hash['HomePhone'] || contact_hash['number'] ||  ""
```

Answer (score 3):

```
contact_hash.values_at('HomePhone','number','home_phone').compact.first
```

Edit:

My first solution did not really give the answer asked for. Here is a modified version, although I think in the case of only 3 options the solution given by @knut is better.

```
contact_hash.values_at('HomePhone','number').push('').compact.first
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`values_at`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-values_at) I suppose:

```
@home_phone = contact_hash.values_at('HomePhone', 'number').find(&:present?).to_s
```

That isn't exactly shorter but it wouldn't be convenient if you had the keys in an array:

```
try_these = %w[HomePhone number]
@home_phone = contact_hash.values_at(*try_these).find(&:present?).to_s
```

You could also wrap that up in a utility method somewhere or patch it into `Hash`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def doit(h, *args)
  args.each {|a| return h[a] if h[a]}
  ""
end

contact_hash = {'Almost HomePhone'=>1, 'number'=>7}
doit(contact_hash, 'HomePhone', 'number')  # => 7
```